# Herencia de entidades en Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony3, doctrine2

estoy con un proyecto en Symfony3 y en el cual quiero hacer herencia entre las entidades mediante anotación yml.
Serian 
                         Inmueble (Padre), (Hijos) Vivienda y Cochera

Tengo tres archivos yml:

Archivo 1

```
Ar\Soft\Alquileres\ModelBundle\Entity\Inmueble\Inmueble:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: Ar\Soft\Alquileres\ModelBundle\Repository\InmuebleRepository
    inheritanceType: SINGLE_TABLE
    discriminatorColumn:
        name: tipo
        type: string
    discriminatorMap:
        vivienda: Vivienda
        cochera: Cochera           
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        valorDeCompra:
            type: float
            nullable: true
            column: valor_de_compra
        fechaDeCompra:
            type: date
            nullable: true
            column: fecha_de_compra
        disponible:
            type: boolean
            nullable: false
            options:
                default: true
        numero:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            column: numero
        superficie:
            type: decimal
            precision: 10
            scale: 0
            nullable: true        
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Archivo 2

```
Ar\Soft\Alquileres\ModelBundle\Entity\Inmueble\Vivienda:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: Ar\Soft\Alquileres\ModelBundle\Repository\ViviendaRepository                
    fields:
        patio:
            type: boolean
            nullable: false
            options:
                default: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Archivo 3

```
Ar\Soft\Alquileres\ModelBundle\Entity\Inmueble\Cochera:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: Ar\Soft\Alquileres\ModelBundle\Repository\CocheraRepository   
    fields:
        tipoDeTecho:
            type: integer
            column: tipo_de_techo
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Al ejecutar desde la carpeta
***php console doctrine:generate:entities ModelBundle***

Me tira error en el archivo 1 (Inmueble) porque no conoce a Vivieda y Cochera cuando intenta analizar el campo "***discriminatorMap***"

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta poner en el descriminatorMap el namespace+nombre de la clase  de las clases a las cuales haces referencia, ese error tiende a ser por no poder resolver el tipo de dato.

Espero sea solo eso.

Comment: Gracias, pero sigue sin funcionar... me tira el mismo error con el namespace :(

Comment: [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                                                                              
  Entity class 'Ar\Soft\Alquileres\ModelBundle\Entity\Inmueble\Vivienda' used in the discriminator map of class 'Ar\Soft\Alquileres\ModelBundle\Entity\Inmueble\Inmueble' does not exis  
  t.

Comment: He encontrado un post en github del mismo error: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/4046 dice que tienes que usar en la entidad padre de la relación en tu caso inmueble @ORM\MappedSuperclass(). Inténtalo y me dices algo, el ejemplo esta al final del post.